# Div into the content of an Entry

Tags: entries

I have a problem when trying to put a div into a content of an entry.

I'm creating entries, building a HTML hierarchy that helps me to manipulate the content with JS. I'm adding divs an build something like this:

```
<div id="cont1" class="content" >
  <h3>Hi I am a title</h3>
  <p>this is the introduction </p>
  <p>this is the content</p>
</div>
```

When I create this, the hierarchy is right, but when I edit it from the CP, all the divs change to this:

```
<p id="cont1" class="content" ></p>
<h3>Hi I am a title</h3>
<p>this is the introduction </p>
<p>this is the content</p>
```

What can I do to prevent this from happening? Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Rich Text field, you'll want to look at the [Redactor setting](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-convertDivs), `convertDivs`.

> convertDivs **(Default setting is true)**
>
> With this option turned on, Redactor will automatically replace divs to paragraphs.

Go in to your field settings:
Craft Admin › Settings › Fields › **Rich Text field name**

Look at the config settings to determine which config file you are using. Then, go in to your `craft/config/redactor/ConfigFile.json` file and edit your redactor settings to exclude the `convertDivs` setting (assuming nothing else in your config file):

```
{
    convertDivs: false
}
```